# Set of recursive sequences as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ denote a set of all real sequences $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ for which the following recursive condition is always true:

$x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}+x_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,...$

Show that $X$ is linear subspace of $\Bbb{R}$, find its basis and dimension.

Ok so I'm familiar with more "traditional" problems on subspaces but this is new to me. I think I can do the 1st part of this problem:

- $(0)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is clearly in $X$
- $\alpha x_{n+2}=\alpha x_{n+1}+\alpha x_n$ where $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$
  is just another sequence $(\alpha x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which lies in 
  $X$,
- Let's say we have $x_n, y_n \in X$. Then
  $(x+y)_{n+2}=(x+y)_{n+1}+(x+y)_n$ so $(x+y)_{n=0}^{\infty}\in X$

Which proves that $X$ is a subspace but what about basis and dimension?

Comment: $X$ isn’t even a subset of $\Bbb R$: it’s a linear subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$. For the rest, do you know the general form of the solution to the recurrence? If so, how many free parameters does it have?

Comment: I thought it's a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}$ too but I just copied the question from my exercise book. As for solving recursive sequences, I haven't done anything like that yet.

Comment: Must be a typo in the exercise book. Knowing the general solution to the recurrence would have made the rest of the problem easy, but you can still solve it. Let me write it up as a proper hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every sequence in $X$ has the form
$$\eqalign{&(a,b,a+b,a+2b,2a+3b,3a+5b,\ldots)\cr
  &\qquad\qquad\qquad=a(1,0,1,1,2,3,\ldots)+b(0,1,1,2,3,5,\ldots)\ .\cr}$$
Therefore the two sequences just shown (the "standard" Fibonacci sequence and a "delayed" Fibonacci sequence) form a basis for $X$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

- How many initial terms do you need to give in order to specify a member of $X$?
- Does every set of initial terms specify a unique member of $X$?

$\Bbb R$ in the exercise must be a typo for $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ or some equivalent notation (e.g., $\Bbb R^\omega$ or $\Bbb R^\infty$).